# change style on select onchange and stop returning to original style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, dopostback

I am trying to use javascript or jQuery to add a class or change css to a span after `onchange="javascript:setTimeout` in the **select**. The problem I have is that after the user changes the form, it changes the css for a second then disappears. How can I make the css remain in place? its seems to auto refresh itself and return back to the original style.

js:

```
$("select").change(function() {
  $(this).closest('div').find('span').css("background-color", "yellow");
});
```

html:

```html
<div id="ctl00_MainContent_ipcResMakePax_ipcPaxBox_rptTravellers_ctl01_pnlDateOfBirth" class="formlistitem">
  <span id="ctl00_MainContent_ipcResMakePax_ipcPaxBox_rptTravellers_ctl01_lblDateOfBirth" class="formlabel">Date of birth</span>
  <br>
  <select name="ctl00$MainContent$ipcResMakePax$ipcPaxBox$rptTravellers$ctl01$ddlDateOfBirthDay" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$MainContent$ipcResMakePax$ipcPaxBox$rptTravellers$ctl01$ddlDateOfBirthDay\',\'\')', 0)" id="ctl00_MainContent_ipcResMakePax_ipcPaxBox_rptTravellers_ctl01_ddlDateOfBirthDay"
    class="selectday">
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: What is __doPostBack() doing? it's not reloading the page by any chance?

Comment: possibly but I don't know how to find out

Comment: [`__doPostBack`](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/667531/doPostBack-function) cause refresh to the page, the why the changes in the style  disappear. Try to use ajax instead of fully postback. If you don't need the postback remove it and the style will remain.

Comment: I cannot amend the original html, I can only add code on top. The site is protected under a framework and I am using a visual web optimizer. Is there anyway to keep the call back but then add the style after it has refreshed the page?

Answer (score 0):

The css updation information(after dropdown select change) must be stored in the database and the backend person should change the class of the span (or add a style to the span appropriately using the server-side technology such as .net may be that you are using) depending on the stored information in the database

Comment: I think doPostBack function is sending information about the select box's state to the server, so the background color information has to be sent with it to the server, or probably its doing the same thing. So

Answer (score 0):

So please consult the backend person to handle the background color change like adding a class to the span element in which we can make the background-color information !important to make it take precedence. So you need to create such a class in the css file used and give the name of the class to be added to the span element for subsequent page loads to the backend person handling .net or so server-side

So 2 classes will be there for the span in this way
class="formlabel your_class'

Answer (score 0):

Based on your constraints, you could use the sessionStorage object via the web storage API to hold the current color value across page posts/reloads:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

The caveat would be that you'd need to clear it manually if the form is used a second time and need a 'fresh' state.